# Custom php.ini override for each user

Tags: php, apache-http-server, lamp

How can I make it so that each user (with Apache's `mod_userdir`) has a `php.ini` file in their home directory that gets used along w/ the system `php.ini` (currently in `/etc/php5/php.ini`?

Cheers!

**EDIT:** This requires PHP `5.2.x`, basically this server can't run PHP `5.3` because of legacy code.

**EDIT:** Most solutions with `.htaccess` and `php_value` won't work here because we use FastCGI with SuExec

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using Virtualhosts, it would look like this:

```
<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80>
    [...]
    PHPINIDir /var/www/web1
    [...]
</VirtualHost>
```

Where php.ini would be located in /var/www/web1/php.ini.

Also check here: http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-specify-a-custom-php.ini-for-a-website-apache2-with-mod_php

Comment: Would this use the system php.ini AND the custom override?

Comment: @kristopher - Yes it would, any value not found in the custom one would be fetched from the system php.ini

Answer (score 0):

With PHP 5.3.0, check out the [.user.ini](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php) files. I haven't tried this, but it sounds like what you want:

> In addition to the main php.ini file, PHP scans for INI files in each directory, starting with the directory of the requested PHP file, and working its way up to the current document root (as set in $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']). Only INI settings with the modes PHP_INI_PERDIR and PHP_INI_USER will be recognized in .user.ini-style INI files.

Or else, create a .htaccess file for each user. Inside .htaccess, modify the [include_path](http://no.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path):

php_value include_path "./php:/php/includes"

Comment: Sorry, we can't use `php_value` inside our .htaccess :(